# How to fix this ngon after beveling the corner?

Tags: topology

I used a bevel on this edge and got this ngon in the mesh. How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Why do you need to fix it, what's wrong with it?

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann: assuming he wants quads or tris, because he wrote "ngons"? ;)

Comment: @Chris Assumingly yes, but I would like to know if he needs quads for a reason (which might be important as to how you convert it best into quads - like as few as possible or preferably many similar sized quads) or if he just believes in the myth that "no matter what purpose the mesh has, always use quads!" Same goes for tris, simple solution would be just to triangulate automatically with `Ctrl`+`T`. But without knowing why he needs it, the result might not be very satisfying.

Comment: I wanted only to use quads because I had problems with adding supporting loops on the edges. I found another way of doing this without adding the ngon. I just extruded and moved the edge and it didnt added extra ngons.